# How does one stop Google Chrome from asking to set up Chrome with you Google Account when Chome is opened

Tags: windows, google-chrome

How do you stop Google Chrome on Windows from asking to login with a Google Account every time  the browser is opened. When I use Chrome on Linux and Mac It does not always open a new tab every time over my requested start page asking to set up Chrome.

[image: Chrome asking to be set up every time]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Open the setting and made changes for the two following options `On startup` and `Home Page`. In first option choose your desired option and in second option choose the `Use the New Tab Page`.
[image]

Comment: If you want to open the `google.com` as your default page then in second option `Home Page` the second option is for you.

Comment: If I choose for option 1 "open the home page" and for option 2 Home Page set to "Open this page"  with value http://www.google.com then it opens 2 pages chrome set up and google.com as pictured above.

Comment: Then you can easily choose under `On startup` option the second one. and personally I'm using these settings and haven't any problem.....:)

Comment: Reopening previouse tabs while it is a good option it is not what I want. I just want google.com to open as the default page, sans the  sign in request for chrome opening in another tab in front of the google.com tab.

Answer (score 3):

[Google Support](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95421&topic=1735115&ctx=topic) has instructions that may assist you in changing what happens when you open chrome.

Try to set the homepage to *Open the following pages* and set **http://www.google.com** as the page to open, on start up.

Comment: Changing the On startup setting in Settings to "Reopen the pages that were open last" fixed it.

Comment: Actually that does not do what I want, since I still want google.com to load as the home page for any new window.

Comment: did you try changing the homepage to **http://google.com**?

Comment: Yes, that seem to have no effect.

Comment: @MrDaniel: Edited my answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with the following registry policy:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome]
"SyncDisabled"=dword:00000001
```

Answer (score 1):

ON that annoyingly persistent login page click the small link near the bottom that says SKIP FOR NOW. It does MORE than 'for now'. It frees up settings.

THEN click the CUSTOMIZE (control panel) button to the right of the address bar, select SETTINGS from the drop-down menu, and then go to the STARTUP options and set your home page (if you had tried to do this previously, you will notice your choice *now* appears). Click OK.

Close Chrome. Reopen. Voila!

Answer (score 0):

For 64-bit Windows, the registry key is: 
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Policies\Google\Chrome] "SyncDisabled"=dword:00000001

I confirm that future.child/Sathya answer above does work on 32-bit Windows.

Comment: If you had the reputation, I would say edit or comment the other correct answer to add that detail.  But since you can't do that, due to reputation yet, adding it as another answer seems reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

Go into your saved passwords and remove any google, gmail saved passwords you see in there.   I had recently changed mine and it was after that I started having the problem.  Once I did that and logged in again...... no problems...