# Disabling chrome://chrome-signin/ tab. Chrome version 51+

Tags: google-chrome

My google chrome (Windows 10, 64 bit) always pops up the chrome://chrome-signin/ tab on startup. I have seen other answers about this problem but they seem to be outdated. On the chrome signin tab there is no option to "skip", and changing things in [Registry](https://superuser.com/a/421528/334410) (I don't even find that Registry key on my system) or [editing preference files](https://superuser.com/questions/432822/disabling-sign-in-tab-on-startup) did not have effect.

Comment: Does resetting Chrome help?.. as in [Chrome keeps asking me to sign in on start up - Google Product Forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/gVQWZbNs64g)